# Getting Paperclip::AdapterRegistry::NoHandlerError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-s3, paperclip

I am trying to create an image uploader that resizes the image and saves 3 copies of it. However I am getting a No Handler Error. Products and Pictures are two different models.

I am using Amazon S3.

Error:

```
Paperclip::AdapterRegistry::NoHandlerError in ProductsController#create

No handler found for "kBOxT7q.jpg"
```

...
A picture has these attributes

```
#<Picture id: 1, product_id: 1, url: nil, created_at: "2014-11-12 23:32:06", 
updated_at: "2014-11-12 23:32:06">
```

...

```
  raise NoHandlerError.new("No handler found for #{target.inspect}")
```

Product controller

```
  def create
    @product = Product.new(product_params)
    if @product.save
      if params[:images]
        params[:images].each { |image|
          @product.pictures.create(image: image)
        }
      end
      flash[:info] = "Product added"
      redirect_to dashboard_path
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
  private

  def product_params
    params.require(:product).permit(..., images_attributes: [:name])
  end
```

Picture.rb

```
class Picture < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product

  # This method associates the attribute ":avatar" with a file attachment
  has_attached_file :image, styles: {
    thumb: '100x100>',
    square: '200x200#',
    medium: '400x400>'
  }

  validates_attachment :image, content_type: {
    content_type: ["image/jpg", "image/png", "image/jpeg"]
  }
end
```

Product Model

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pictures, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :pictures
```

View

```
<%= form_for(@product) do |f| %>
  <div class="control-group">
    <%= f.label :pictures, :class => 'control-label' %>
    <div class="controls">
      <%= file_field_tag "images[]", type: :file, multiple: true %>
    </div>
  </div>
  ...
<% end %>
```

## debug output

Request

```
Parameters:
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"kPbpAg5dr4nbl9k2qt7hQ+BDPHZEHGPmImuxxYMxXpI=",
 "product"=>{"name"=>"aaah",
 "price"=>"1.00",
 "category"=>"1",
 "quantity"=>"2",
 "shop_id"=>"1"},
 "images"=>["kBOxT7q.jpg",
 "ZBBukdp.jpg"],
 "commit"=>"Add Product"}
```

Answer (score 0):

One problem which is possible is that when we are supposed to upload files from form, we need to add html: { multipart: true } to the form.
In your case

```
  <%= form_for(@product), html: { multipart: true } do |f| %>
```

Considering the request parameters, it is getting string for image names rather than image files.

Then we need to permit image for image_attributes rather than name